# Array of an array object

Tags: javascript

I have an array named 'questions' and I have an object variable associated to it that is also an array named 'choices'.

```
var questions = [
{
question: "What type of business do you run?",
choices: ['Business to Business - Provide products and/or services to other 
         businesses', 'Business to Business to Consumer - Provide products 
         and/or services to other businesses for consumers', 
         'Business to Consumer - Provide products and/or services to 
         consumers'],
choiceValues: [1, 2, 3],
}
```

I would like to use the length of 'choices' in a for loop, as seen below. Is this syntax correct? I can't seem to the 'points' variable to increase.

```
function displayScore() 
{
var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});
var points = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) 
{
    for (var j = 0; j < questions[i].choices.length; j++)
    {
        if (selections[i] === questions[i].choices[j]) 
        {
            points = points + questions[i].choiceValues[j];
        }
    }
}
score.append('You got ' + points + ' points!');
return score;
}
```

An example of 'selections' would be: [0,4,0,1,0,1,0,1].

Comment: Have you verified what `questions[i].choices[j]` is? Does it match what you expect it to be? Also, what is `selections`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate 'selections' is an array containing the users answers to the questions. I'm using the inner for loop to check which answer out of a list their answer matches. Based on which answer it matches, a certain number of points are assigned, defined by 'choiceValues'.

Comment: Provide an example of `selections`

Comment: @luisenrike I've updated the question

Comment: @RoKath what is choiceValue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `selections[i]` is a `number` `(0)` and `questions[i].choices[j]` is a `string` `('Business to Business - Provide products and/or services to other businesses')`, so, `if (selections[i] === questions[i].choices[j])` won't work (always `false`).

You can check instead for the index of the choice:

```
if (selections[i] === j) 
{
    points = points + questions[i].choiceValues[j];
}
```

Also, the inner `for` is useless, you can do this:

```
function displayScore() 
{
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});
    var points = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
        points += questions[i].choiceValues[selections[i]];
    }
    score.append('You got ' + points + ' points!');
    return score;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.